# How to capture the output of a process in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to capture the output of a main class launch by `sbt` via a `ProcessBuilder` but that doesn't work. What am I missing here ?

The result is printed in the console but not by the println

```
val result = Seq("sbt", "runMain example.Hello")
  .#<(new ByteArrayInputStream("a".getBytes()))
  .!!
println(s"result=$result")
```

Comment: What's the return type of `result`?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation when trying to use beeline.

This worked for us:

```
val stdout = new StringBuilder
val stderr = new StringBuilder

var commandSeq = Seq("beeline"
  , "-u"
  , ConfigProvider.config.BeelineConfig.Url
  , "-n"
  , ConfigProvider.config.BeelineConfig.UserName
  , "-p"
  , ConfigProvider.config.BeelineConfig.Password
  , "--outputformat=xmlattr"
  , "-f"
  , filePath)

hiveConfArgs.foreach(arg => {
  commandSeq = commandSeq :+ "--hivevar"
  commandSeq = commandSeq :+ arg
})

commandSeq ! ProcessLogger(stdout append _, stderr append _ + "\n")

(stdout.toString, stderr.toString)
```